# Locally compact Hausdorff space

Tags: general-topology

How can you prove the following statement:

If a Hausdorff space $S$ is locally compact, then for any point $a \in S$ and any open neighbourhood $U$ of $a$ there is an open set $V$ in $S$ such that $a \in V \subset \bar{V} \subset U$ and $\bar{V}$ is compact.

Comment: Sometimes this is given as the definition of locally compact. What is the definition you're working with?

Comment: Try finding such an open set in the one point compactification.

Comment: @Jose27 My definition is $S$ is locally compact if every point in $S$ is an interior point of a compact subset of $S$.

Answer (score 0):

By your definition, a Hausdorff space $S$ is locally compact if for every $x \in S$ there exists $W$ open and $K$ compact such that 
$$x \in W \subset K$$
Let $U$ open, $U\ni x$. Then $x \in U \cap W \subset K$. Let's work now in the compact space $K$. We have the open subset $U\cap W$ contaning $x$. The compact subset $K \backslash (U\cap W)$ does not contain $x$.  The following is a standard argument: for every $y \in K \backslash (U\cap W)$ consider $U_y \ni x$, $V_y \ni y$ so that $U_y \cap V_y = \emptyset$. Since $ K \backslash (U\cap W)$ is compact finitely many $V_{y_1}$, $\ldots$, $V_{y_n}$ will cover $K \backslash (U\cap W)$. Let $U' = \cap_{i=1}^n U_{y_i}$. We have $U' \subset U$ open in $K$ and therefore open in $X$. Moreover $\bar U' \subset U$.

More or less, it follows from the fact that a compact Hausdorff space has strong separation properties (it is normal).